# Mysql join syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a problem here right now in my project using codeigniter and it cost a lot of my time (tbh). I have a table in my database named contestants that has a columns of (id, event_id, name, gender, address, date_created) and tbl_rate that has a columns of (rate_id, judge_id, cont_id, score). I want to join this 2 tables but something is wrong:

[image]

and here is my query:

```
public function getresult()
{
 $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `event_id`, `name`, `score` FROM contestants JOIN 
 tbl_rate ON `contestants.id` = `tbl_rate.cont_id`';

 $query = $this->db->get($sql);
 return $query->result_array();
 }
```

Comment: Please don't post text in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste as text directly into your question.

Comment: There's a codeigniter `join` function, did you try that?

Comment: sorry my bad. Its my first time asking a question here.

Comment: the screenshot image error doesn't support the code you posted. There's an additional `SELECT * FROM` coming from somewhere else and additional ticks `\`` also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, and I don't know where that extra SELECT * FROM came from

Comment: it's probably coming from a CI core method or from your class

Comment: you'll need to post more code. The people who gave you answers so far won't be able to help you any further. They got rep from it and just might end there.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your backticks:

```
select `id`,
    `event_id`,
    `name`,
    `score`
from contestants
join tbl_rate on `contestants`.`id` = `tbl_rate`.`cont_id`
```

Or better not use them at all by using proper identifiers:

```
select id,
    event_id,
    name,
    score
from contestants
join tbl_rate on contestants.id = tbl_rate.cont_id
```

Comment: @Mikko - *Not working* - how? Do you get an error? incorrect result?

Comment: yeah, it showed me the same error that I posted earlier.

Comment: @Mikko In  your screenshot I can see you are using backticks twice. Use once on the table identifier and once on the column identifier. **However, I'd recommend not using them at all**. Just try out the second query I posted.

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT id, event_id, name, score FROM contestants JOIN tbl_rate ON contestants.id = tbl_rate.cont_id';
 $query = $this->db->get($sql);    still, I get the same error msg

Comment: @Mikko - Did you try executing this query directly against the database? Please ping here the complete error message.

Comment: @GurV see my comments under their question and if you haven't seen their screenshot error; this goes deeper than posted.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT contestants.id, contestants.event_id, contestants.name, tbl_rate.score
                           WHERE contestants.id = tbl_rate.cont_id");
return $query->result_array();
```